# Change the current page using a plugin

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I am using phonegap.
Currently on android I'm able to change the page using the really simple function that I have done:

```
public boolean execute(String action, CordovaArgs args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) cordova.getActivity();
        ma.reload(args.getString(0));
        return (true);
    }
```

and in the mainActivity:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/" + url, 1000);
```

But I'm new to objective C and iOs and I'm unable to find the correct keywords or a beginning of answer.
I'am able to have the equivalent of the `execute` function but then I have no idea how to get the mainActivity and reload the page

Until now I'n my plugin I have the following code but it's not working :/

```
- (void)execute:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
//id message = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
 id message = @"buy/buy.html";       
 [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:message]]];
}
```

EDIT:

I have try to do the following:

```
@implementation Redirect

- (void)execute:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    id message = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* newUrl = message;
    NSString* javaScript = nil;
    NSString *jsCallBack = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"changeUrl('%@');", newUrl];



    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:message];
    javaScript = [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:jsCallBack];
    [self writeJavascript:javaScript];
}
@end
```

and in the html:

```
 window.changeUrl = function (url){
        alert("ici");
        navigator.app.loadUrl(url);
    }

var Redirect= function(){
    return cordova.exec( function(data){ alert(data);console.log("Success");}, function(){ console.log("Fail");},
                            "Redirect",
                            "execute",
                            [location.href]);
};
```

I'm sure the plugin is called when but if I put an alert in the `changeUrl` function nothing is displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution so in the plugin:

```
- (void)execute:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    id message = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    AppDelegate* mainDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [mainDelegate reloadUrl:message];
}
```

in the AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)reloadUrl:(NSString *)url
{
 #if __has_feature(objc_arc)
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
#else
    self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
#endif  

    self.viewController.startPage = url;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window reloadInputViews];
}
```

and I simply call the plugin in js:

```
return cordova.exec( function(data){ alert(data);console.log("Success");}, function(){ console.log("Fail");},
                                    "Redirect",
                                    "execute",
                                    ["index2.hmtl"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a couple of different ways (that I know of).  Make sure you have the `changeUrl` function in the window namespace for both approaches.

1st Approach (this can be triggered from anywhere, doesn't have to be a cordova plugin class) -

```
function changeUrl(url){
    navigator.app.loadUrl(url);
}

AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString* newUrl = @"file:///android_asset/www/buy/buy.html";
NSString *jsCallBack = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"changeUrl('%@');", newUrl];
[appDelegate.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

2nd Approach (this must be triggered from a cordova plugin class, which is what your current code is in) -

```
function changeUrl(url){
    navigator.app.loadUrl(url);
}

NSString* newUrl = @"file:///android_asset/www/buy/buy.html";
NSString* javaScript = nil;
NSString *jsCallBack = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"changeUrl('%@');", newUrl];
javaScript = [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:jsCallBack];
[self writeJavascript:javaScript];
```